# Filtering search using checkboxes

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I have a form that allows users to search my website. The site has different sections, each one corresponding to a custom post type (it's based on Wordpress), so I've added a filter where the user can check in which of the sections they want to search.

How can I detect which checkboxes have been ticked so that when the results page is loaded they are correctly filtered? Can I do it with $_POST or do I need a cookie?

I'm sure this is pretty simple but I have little experience with forms and posting values, so I need a little direction. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a GET form. then, access via $_GET. WordPress already have some $_GET automatic variables to filter (like taxonomies), in default archives. Also, you need to register your custom $_GET variables.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, thank you. If you can turn your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to tick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct option is use GET. This way, filter options will be on url, being able to share, refresh and bookmark.

Also, WordPress already provide some GET filters (taxonomies).

WordPress recommends you to register your GET variables for security.